# Problem with foreign letters in web application build with java

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, servlets

So I have been building a simple application where a user can input some data into an html form on a webpage. However after that data is sent with polish special letters it is converted into HTML dec. code like for example `"&#322;"` into my java backend code and not into the actual letters I would like to display. I have tried changin charsets encodings in many various ways however none of my solutions seems to work so after spending a few hours I decided to ask here.

I've tried putting doing those things:

```
<html lang="pl">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO 8859-16">
```

my backend looks like this

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    private EpdFileSender sender;

    @Autowired
    public WelcomeController(EpdFileSender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleInputRequest(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name, @RequestParam String status1,
            @RequestParam String status2, @RequestParam String status3, ModelMap model) throws Exception {

        model.put("name", name);
        model.put("status1", status1);
        model.put("status2", status2);
        model.put("status3", status3);



        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO 8859-16">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
    <title>Smart Door Card</title>


  </head>

<form action="/" method="POST" class="form-signin" autocomplete="off">
  <i class="fas fa-pen-square fa-7x"></i>
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal logo-text">Smart Door Card</h1>

  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control top" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
  <input type="text" name="status1" class="form-control middle1" placeholder="Set Status">
  <input type="text" name="status2" class="form-control middle2" placeholder="Set Status">
  <input type="text" name="status3" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Set Status">

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block set-button" type="submit">Set Your Card</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted logo-footer">&copy; The Smart Door Card</p>
</form>
```

I would like the polish special letters that are put by the user to display like letters in the app and not in code.

Comment: I'd use UTF-8 as the charset and URL encoding/decoding to send text back to the server. Btw, you don't show us how you are sending the data to the server.

Comment: My bad, I updated the code, I am using an html form and submit button. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an issue, turns out I needed to add this into my web.xml

```
  <filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```